# How to export content to campaign monitor?

Tags: views, rules, nodes

How to export content to [campaign monitor](https://www.campaignmonitor.com):

- the admin will chose content from different content types
- that content will be exported to campaig nmonitor
- will be separated in different campaigns lists
  Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: What format, CSV, JSON, XML, something else? Also: what is "campaign monitor"? Cconsider adding a hyperlink via an edit to your question ...

Comment: Export should be HTML format.

Comment: Have a look at my answer at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30968/how-to-create-an-excel-file-with-drupal/190145#190145 ... If you change "excel" to "html" in it (as in your case here), it would also answer this question I think